# Python Pandas yerr from dataframe for plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a simple plot from my dataframe. I've provided a reproducible example of what I'm doing now. It creates the bar chart I'd like buit without the y error bars to show the SEM of each mean value. How do I get the SEM values to show as error bars?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Measures' : 'Pre Var 1',
       'Mean' : 2,
       'SEM' : 1}])

df[['Measures', 'Mean']].plot(x='Measures', kind='bar', yerr=df['SEM'])
```

This is what my code currently produces

[image: This is what it produces]

This is the desired graph

[image]

Comment: I am sorry what do you want exactly ?

Comment: Added a reference graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(df['Measures'], df['Mean'], yerr=df['SEM'])
```

Comment: I tried it, but it gave my actual dataset's plot a lot of overlapping labels

Comment: Fixed it, just had to rotate the xticks

Comment: @FallingInForward it's ok for you can validate the solution and close the question thanks